# Can not filter with django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using django-filter and django rest framework to filter data. My issue is that I get back all my data and not the filtered ones.

This is the view that renders the page with the filters form:

```
class MyProductsFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = Product
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    template_name = "products/my_products.html"
    context_object_name = "my_products"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyProductsFilterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["my_products"] = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related().order_by("-timestamp")
        return context
```

When the apply button is clicked in the filters form the following function is called:

```
function applyFilters(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var FiltersForm = $(".filters-form");
     $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/filtered-products/',
        data: FiltersForm.serialize(),
         success: function(res) {
            console.log(res)
         },
         error: function (res) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
     })
}
```

The filters form is serialized and a get request is made to get the filtered data with the following drf class view:

```
class FilteredProductsListAPIView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

This the url for the drf class:

```
url(r"^filtered-products/",
   views.FilteredProductsListAPIView.as_view(), name="get-filtered-products")
```

Instead of getting back the result of the filters being applied, I get all my data.

Comment: try to change `FiltersForm`  value to `$(".filters-form")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r"^filtered-products/",
   views.FilteredProductsListAPIView.as_view(), name="get-filtered-products")
```

here to call **FilteredProductsListAPIView** , and your query is

```
queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

in this view, you must define get_queryset function, if you want some filtering on db,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = SOME_FILTERING
    return query
```